# NestedSlot presenter with own url- how to setup url for NestedSlot presenters

Tags: url, gwt, proxy, gwtp, gwt-platform

I have parent presenter: `UsersListPresenter` that contains nested presenter: `UserPresenter` in NestedSlot.

```
  public class UsersListPresenter extends ApplicationPresenter<UsersListPresenter.MyView, UsersListPresenter.MyProxy> implements UsersListUiHandlers,
OpenWindowEvent.OpenModaHandler, UserAddedEvent.UserAddedHandler {
    @ProxyStandard
    @NameToken(ClientRouting.Url.users)
    @UseGatekeeper(IsUserLoggedGatekeeper.class)
    public interface MyProxy extends TabContentProxyPlace<UsersListPresenter> {}

    @TabInfo(container = AppPresenter.class)
    static TabData getTabLabel(IsUserLoggedGatekeeper adminGatekeeper) {
        return new MenuEntryGatekeeper(ClientRouting.Label.users, 1, adminGatekeeper);
    }

    public interface MyView extends View, HasUiHandlers<UsersListUiHandlers> {
        void setUsers(List<UserDto> users);
        void addUser(UserDto user);
    }

    public static final NestedSlot SLOT_USER_WINDOW = new NestedSlot();
    //interface Driver extends SimpleBeanEditorDriver<UserDto, UserEditor> {}
    private static final UserService userService = GWT.create(UserService.class);
    private AppPresenter appPresenter;
    private UserTestPresenter userPresenter;

    @Inject
    UsersListPresenter(EventBus eventBus, MyView view, MyProxy proxy, AppPresenter appPresenter, UserTestPresenter userPresenter) {
        super(eventBus, view, proxy, appPresenter, AppPresenter.SLOT_TAB_CONTENT);
        this.appPresenter = appPresenter;
        this.userPresenter = userPresenter;
        getView().setUiHandlers(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onBind() {
        super.onBind();
        updateList();
        setInSlot(SLOT_USER_WINDOW, userPresenter);
        addRegisteredHandler(OpenWindowEvent.getType(), this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onReveal() {
        super.onReveal();
        initializeApplicationUiComponents(ClientRouting.Label.users);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpenModal(OpenWindowEvent event) {
        openModal(event.getUser());
    }
    @Override
    public void openModal(UserDto user) {
        userPresenter.openModal(user);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class UsersListView extends ViewWithUiHandlers<UsersListUiHandlers> implements UsersListPresenter.MyView {
    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, UsersListView> {}

    @UiField
    SimplePanel windowSlot;

    @Inject
    UsersListView(Binder uiBinder) {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
    @Override
    public void setInSlot(Object slot, IsWidget content) {
        if (slot == UsersListPresenter.SLOT_USER_WINDOW) {
            windowSlot.setWidget(content);
        }
    };
}
```

---

```
 public class UserTestPresenter extends Presenter<UserTestPresenter.MyView, UserTestPresenter.MyProxy> implements UserTestUiHandlers {
    public interface MyView extends View, HasUiHandlers<UserTestUiHandlers> {
        void openModal(UserDto user);
    }
    @ProxyStandard
    @NameToken("/user/{userid}")
    public interface MyProxy extends ProxyPlace<UserTestPresenter> {
    }

    private PlaceManager placeManager;

    @Inject
    public UserTestPresenter(EventBus eventBus, MyView view, MyProxy proxy, PlaceManager placeManager) {
        super(eventBus, view, proxy, UsersListPresenter.SLOT_USER_WINDOW);
        this.placeManager = placeManager;
        getView().setUiHandlers(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void prepareFromRequest(PlaceRequest request) {
        GWT.log("Prepare from request " + request.getNameToken());
    }
    @Override
    protected void onReveal() {
        super.onReveal();
    };
    public void openModal(UserDto user) {
        getView().openModal(user);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSave(UserDto user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MaterialToast.fireToast("onSaveClick in new presenter for " + user.toString());
    }
    @Override
    public void onClose() {
        PlaceRequest placeRequest = new PlaceRequest.Builder().nameToken("/users/{userid}").with("userid", "list").build();
        placeManager.revealPlace(placeRequest);
    }
```

---

```
public class UserTestView extends ViewWithUiHandlers<UserTestUiHandlers> implements UserTestPresenter.MyView {
    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, UserTestView> {}

    @UiField
    MaterialRow main;
    @UiField
    MaterialWindow window;
    @UiField
    MaterialLabel userName, userFullName;
    @UiField
    MaterialButton saveButton;
    private HandlerRegistration saveButtonClickHandler;

    @Inject
    UserTestView(Binder uiBinder) {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        // adding default click handler
        saveButtonClickHandler = saveButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void openModal(final UserDto user) {
        userName.setText(user.getEmail());
        userFullName.setText(user.getId() + " " + user.getEmail());
        saveButtonClickHandler.removeHandler();
        saveButtonClickHandler = saveButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                getUiHandlers().save(user);
            }
        });
        window.openWindow();
    }


}
```

when user from list is clicked the window with clicked users is opened. At this moment **url should change** from `http://localhost:8080/cms/#/users/list` to `http://localhost:8080/cms/#/user/3`

for better understanding below is screencast from that code:
[image]

and now some job done, but still not ideal:
[image]

here is my gwtp configuration:

```
public class ClientModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(RestyGwtConfig.class).asEagerSingleton();
        install(new Builder()//
        .defaultPlace(ClientRouting.HOME.url)//
        .errorPlace(ClientRouting.ERROR.url)//
        .unauthorizedPlace(ClientRouting.LOGIN.url)//
        .tokenFormatter(RouteTokenFormatter.class).build());
        install(new AppModule());
        install(new GinFactoryModuleBuilder().build(AssistedInjectionFactory.class));
        bind(CurrentUser.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(IsAdminGatekeeper.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(IsUserLoggedGatekeeper.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(ResourceLoader.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }
}
```

As You can see I use **tokenFormatter(RouteTokenFormatter.class)**

how it can be achieved with gwtp framework?

Comment: Just curious: why do you want to change the URL of the `UsersListPresenter` ?

Comment: Not the `UsersListPresenter`. When the window shows up is `UserTestPresenter` and it is proxy place with it's own url. This url should be displayed. Thanks to that user can access concrete user window from url, without the need to manually find and click on user.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to change the URL of your `UserListPresenter` to support passing in the user id as an optional parameter:

```
@NameToken("/users/{userid}")
public interface MyProxy extends ProxyPlace<UserListPresenter> {
}
```

You need to override the `prepareFromRequest` method of your `UserListPresenter` and there you check if the userid is set and open your modal window if it is.

```
@Override
public void prepareFromRequest(PlaceRequest request) {
    String userid = request.getParameter("userid", "list");
    if (userid != "list") {
        # open modal
    }
    else {
        # close modal
    }
}
```

You also need to change the logic when you click your on a user in your list:

```
@Override
public void onOpenModal(OpenWindowEvent event) {
    PlaceRequest placeRequest = new PlaceRequest.Builder()
      .nameToken("/users/{userid}")
      .with("userid", event.getUser().getId())
        .build();
    placeManager.revealPlace(placeRequest);
}
```

This will change the URL and open the modal.

Comment: It doesen't work. I am getting a url: `http://localhost:8080/cms/#/users/%7Buserid%7D`, and after entering concrete user url: `http://localhost:8080/cms/#/users/1` I am getting an error page

Comment: I don't get error message. It just displays error place, like there is wrong ulr f.e.

Comment: so to clarify you get the error page when you navigate to `http://localhost:8080/cms/#/users/1` ? 

Did you make sure to annotate your `ProxyPlace` for your  `UserListPresenter` with `@NameToken("/users/{userid}")` 

I also updated the answer regarding the issue with the url escaped

Comment: 2 thinks don't work, 1. Entering url to concrete user directly: `http://localhost:8080/cms/#/user/3`  or `http://localhost:8080/cms/#/users/list` and 1. When I enter user place from ui menu I am getting this ugly url: `http://localhost:8080/cms/#/users/%7Buserid%7D`- by the way this one work when entering to the browser
I've updated post.

Comment: How did you implement the `User` menu item ?
You need to make sure to navigate to `http://localhost:8080/cms/#/users/li‌​st` and **not** http://localhost:8080/cms/#/users

Comment: I did not implement it. I use gwtp mechanism for that. For `UserListPresenter` I extend `com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.Presenter` and this to generate label: `@TabInfo(container = AppPresenter.class)
    static TabData getTabLabel(IsUserLoggedGatekeeper adminGatekeeper) {
        return new MenuEntryGatekeeper(ClientRouting.Label.users, 1, adminGatekeeper);
    }` base on this example: https://gwtp-sample-tab.appspot.com/ (my menu is just a tab panel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121936/discussion-between-masterdany88-and-umit).